# Character Spacing in powerpoint vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to change the character spacing to the selected text from the paragraph. But my below code change the character spacing for the entire text box. Can anyone help me with this.

For e.g., I just need to increase the character spacing only for the selected text from the entire sentence. Shown in the below picture

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 3
```

Also below code can help me with my purpose. But here the issue is, how can i get the 20 and 45 from the macro.

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(20, 45).Font.Spacing = 3
```

[image: Below is the example, would like to increase the character spacing of only text "constants may not be available to you" from the entire sentence]

Comment: You will need to loop over the string and check the character font format for each letter, marking the beginning and end of any bold section of text, then use those positions to run the line you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 3
```

refers to the entire text range of the selected shape.  Instead, use:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange2.Font.Spacing = 3
```

This will act only on the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop over the string and check the character font format for each letter, marking the beginning and end of any bold section of text, then use those positions to apply the spacing:

```vb
Dim shp As Shape, i As Long, pStart As Long, n As Long

Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)

pStart = 0

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange
    n = .Characters.Count
    For i = 1 To n
        If .Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold Then
            If pStart = 0 Then
                pStart = i
            ElseIf pStart > 0 And i = n Then 'ending on bold text
                .Characters(pStart, i - pStart).Font.Spacing = 3
            End If
        Else
            If pStart > 0 Then 'transitioning to non-bold
                .Characters(pStart, i - pStart).Font.Spacing = 3
                pStart = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just want to increase the character spacing of only selected text. not the bold one.